# filter for attribute values in Boost.Log(V2)

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I'm trying to create a somewhat log4c-alike Boost logger.
Have decorated my log record with things like "File", "Function", "Line", etc.
Have also created a custom filter, which gets all the attribute set via

```
bool Filter(const boost::log::attribute_value_set& set)
{
  for (boost::log::attribute_value_set::const_iterator it=set.begin(); it != set.end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << "Name " << it->first << std::endl;
    }
[...]
}
```

The base of the log is severity filter is created via

```
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT( my_logger,boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt < SeverityLevel > )
```

where SeverityLevel is a customer enum.

I'm creating the log records like:

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(),level) << boost::log::add_value("Mask", mask) << boost::log::add_value("Line", line) << boost::log::add_value("File", File) << boost::log::add_value("Function", Function) << l_line;
```

Where "line", "File", "Function" are the 'obvious' values from **LINE**, **FILE** and **FUNCTION** macros (meh I don't know how to escape double underscores, sorry).

To my surprise, the logrecord only contain the "global" record members like "Severity", "LineID", "TimeStamp", etc. but NOT my custom attributes
created at log time (e.g. Line, File, Function, etc.). Obviously they are written to the log destination with my custom formatter without any problem.

I am obviously missing something pretty straightforward, mind me was 
googling this for half a day without any luck.

Can someone guide me what the heck I'm missing?
Thanks,

Comment: Damn. I missed this completely   www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_attribute_manips_dont_affect_filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So regular attributes are appended after filters are executed (which i find pretty strange, but this is the case). So I need to use scoped attributes